# Test changed object in a method that does not return anything in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, monkeypatching

I have got a function:

```
def function_to_test(df, filename):
     df = process_df(df, arg1, arg2, arg3)
     df.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

And I want to mock to_csv function to check if the dataframe object was processed properly before saving to file. I know that I want to patch "to_csv" but I do not know how to get the object it was called on?

```
def test_function(self):
    input_df = pd.DataFrame(... some df )
    expected_result = pd.DataFrame(... some df )

    with mock.patch("pandas.core.frame.DataFrame.to_csv"):
         function_to_test(input_df, "dummy_filename")
         # assert expected_result == processed_df
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use `mock.patch.object` with `autospec=True` to get the `df` which is passed in as `self` in `df.to_csv()`

`your_script.py:`

```
def function_to_test(df, filename):
     df = process_df(df, arg1, arg2, arg3)
     df.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

`test.py:`

```
from pandas._testing import assert_frame_equal

def test_function(self):
    input_df = pd.DataFrame(... some df )
    expected_result = pd.DataFrame(... some df )

    with mock.patch.object(pd.DataFrame, "to_csv", autospec=True) as mock_to_csv:
         function_to_test(input_df, "dummy_filename")
         mock_call_obj = mock_to_csv.call_args_list[0]
         modified_df = mock_call_obj.arg[0]
         assert_frame_equal(modified_df, expected_result)
```

`mock_to_csv.call_args_list` is a list of all calls. If `custom_to_csv` is called multiple times, this will contain information of all the calls in the order they are called. Each element is a `call` object that has `.args` attribute for `args`. The 1st arg is `self` which is `df`.

If `custom_to_csv` is indeed called multiple times, you can filter by 2nd arg, i.e. the filename. E.g.:

```
call_wanted_to_check = next(filter(lambda x: x.arg[1]==desired_filepath, mock_to_csv.call_args_list))
df_desired = call_wanted_to_check.arg[0]
```